# Curl acces elements Xml response after login website

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am lost here. I dont see what is going wrong here. First I login, than I want to acces a page that has a Xml output and then store the elements to a php variable so I can use it. But I keep getting empty results, what am I doing wrong ?

This is the Xml response I am trying to collect.

```
<xmlresponse>
<time>December 20 - 14:27</time>
<country>United States</country>
<redstar messages="0"><!--[CDATA[0]]--></redstar>
<yellowstar><!--[CDATA[0]]--></yellowstar>
<bluestar><!--[CDATA[0]]--></bluestar>
<silverstar><!--[CDATA[0]]--></silverstar>
<people><!--[CDATA[<a href="../jail.php" target="MainFrame"--><img src="/site/images/new/topleft/j_yes.gif" alt="" onmouseover="ddrivetip('There are<br />65<br />people in here');" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();">]]&gt;</people>
<cars><!--[CDATA[<a href="../money/cars.php" target="MainFrame"--><img src="/site/images/new/topleft/gta_no.gif" alt="" onmouseover="ddrivetip('You can\'t<br />cars');" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();">]]&gt;</cars>
<laas><!--[CDATA[<a href="../money/gg.php" target="MainFrame"--><img src="/site/images/new/topleft/gg_yes.gif" alt="" onmouseover="ddrivetip('You can<br />do do it');" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();">]]&gt;</laas>
<loop><!--[CDATA[<a href="../money/loop.php" target="MainFrame"--><img src="/site/images/new/topleft/row_yes.gif" alt="" onmouseover="ddrivetip('You can<br />do this');" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();">]]&gt;</loop>
<fly><!--[CDATA[<a href="../airport.php" target="MainFrame"--><img src="/site/images/new/topleft/fly_no.gif" alt="" onmouseover="ddrivetip('You can\'t<br />travel');" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();">]]&gt;</fly>
</xmlresponse>
```

And this is how I login and then want to get the response from the php with the xml result.

```
$postFieldsLogin = array("email" => $emailacc,"password" => $passwordacc,); 
//initial request with login data
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.site.nl/main/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postFieldsLogin));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie-name');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/var/www/ip4.x/file/tmp');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
$response = curl_exec($ch);if (curl_error($ch)) {echo curl_error($ch);}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.site.cc/site/topleft/xmlphp.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
$simpleXMLElement = simplexml_load_string($response);
$description = (string)$simpleXMLElement->xmlresponse->cars;

echo $description;
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? The response echo shows the xml I posted but the description variable shows no result? The end result will be that I use Simple Html Dom to get the img scr in it.

Comment: loose the `xmlresponse` and try `$description = (string)$simpleXMLElement->cars;`, if you var_dump(simpleXMLElement), you can see what's actually in the element (not 100% though)

Comment: The XML is invalid anyway, it has raw HTML in some tags (cars included) which aren't valid XML (unencoded <> in attributes and unclosed img tags).

Comment: Tried what you said @Naruto. Gives the result string(194). So what is next.. How do I get the info. My end goal is to get the image from the img tag. So I thought I need to store the variable from the xml result first than move from there. But that does not even work..